# Draw circles around points

Tags: qgis, circle, boundaries

[image]I have a CSV layer of points which I have succesfully imported into QGIS. My assets are a bit like wireless access points and I cannot have any of the points on the same channel within 2km. I therefore want to be able to click on a point and it automatically draw a 2km circle around it, and then have the ability to click on 4 points at the same time to ensure the circles do not overlap, if it does then click off a point which will make the circle dissapear and I try another point.

So far I have tried adding a 'proposed channel' column in my CSV and reimporting the data every time I change a single point channel but this is taking forever... Does anybody have any better ideas?

[image]

Comment: You can also try Vector - Geoproccessing tools - Buffer

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why you want to do it interactively. You can use QGIS expressions to visualize those points that have a nearest neighbour less than 2 km away and than decide in each case what to do. You can use differnt forms of visualization, I show here one that connects points nearer than 2km with a line.

The advantage to use geometry generator: when you move or delete points, the line immediately adapts to the new situation and the lines change accordingly. So you can observe the effects in realtime. When all lines disappeared, than you are sure that you don't have any points closer than 2 km.

Of course, you could also use a simple expression like `buffer ($geometry, 2000)` to draw a 2km circle around your points, but than you have to look manually for points within this distance.

The expression below first evaluates if there are any points nearer than 2km and only than draws a line. You could use this expression as well to generate a new field with the field calculator that calculates the distance to the nearest point, using just this part of the expression: `distance ($geometry, collect_geometries (overlay_nearest (@layer, $geometry )))`

But I advice to try this: Add an additional symbol layer to your point layer, set it to Geometry generator, Geometry type: line and paste this expression:

```
if ( 
    distance (
        $geometry, 
        collect_geometries (
            overlay_nearest (
                @layer, 
                $geometry 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) < 2000 , 
    make_line (
        $geometry , 
        overlay_nearest ( 
            @layer , 
            $geometry )
        ), 
    NULL
)
```

You can see from the measure tool on the bottom right (red box) how far is 2 km on my map canvas and you can see that points with a distance less than this are connected with a line:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for this, looks great. Im a bit of a newbie to QGIS, however do I add a new symbol layer? Thanks.

Comment: Click the green plus to add a symbol layer (see upper right part on the screenshot), than set symbol layer type to geometry generator

Comment: See documentation: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#moderate-fa-adding-symbol-layers

Comment: this does not appear to have worked for me...i am getting dots inside my original points. I do not know how to attach a photo but I am not getting the lines like you are yet my formula and options look the same

Comment: You can add a screeshot in your original question, just edit it and revise your question

Comment: I have added a pic @babel

Comment: That does not help much, I don't see any settings (your symbol layer, the expression you pasted etc.) By the way: better insert your picture at the end of the question, after a line break, than the question itself can be read easier

Comment: I mean this part of the settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG6Ya.png

Comment: I have added the settgins pic for you.

Comment: Looks fine. Could be a problem of projection used. What is the CRS of your point layer? Go to layer Properties of your point layer, Information tab. What CRS and what units of measurement do you have there?

Comment: See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oWuX.png

Comment: it says EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic and the unit is degrees @babel

Comment: OK, that's why! Your distances area measured in degrees, thus 2000 degrees! The whole earth has 2*180=360 degrees (E/W) and 2*90 = 180 degrees N/S

Comment: You have to reproject your layer to a projected CRS, one that uses meters as units. EPSG:3857 theoretically does the job, but it is not a good CRS for measurements.Depending on where on Earth you are, the answer which CRS to use is quite different, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382608/88814

Comment: To reproject, export your layer (right click / export / savefeatures as... ; than select the CRS you want to reproject to) or use the reproject tool from Menu Vector / Datamanagement Tools

Comment: thats working now, thanks! I dont suppose there is any functionality within Qgis to automattically assign channel numbers for me is there? I am probably asking too much of it but if it could assign a channel number from 0,9,18,27,36,45,54,63 and ensure no channel was overlapping within a 2km radius that would be amazing! otherwise ill do it with pen and paper and highlighters! Thanks.

Comment: (Almost) everything is possible in QGIS. However, I don't understand what exactely you mean with "channel numbers". Plase elaborate (best with screenshot/drawing) - probably it's better to open a new thread, because this already is another question and the policy on this site is: one question per thread. Feel free however to post a link to this question here.

Comment: thanks for advice so far, hopefully makes sense here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382801/generate-radio-channel-number-keeping-2km-buffer

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Rule-based layer styling with the geometry generator:

Set a filter rule as: `is_selected()`
and geometry generator: `buffer($geometry, 2000, 5)`:

[image]

And an else rule with simple marker styling:

[image]

Then select points:
[image]