# Generate Radio Channel Number Keeping 2km Buffer

Tags: qgis, point, layers, buffer

I have point data and each point has a serial number (as shown in the screenshot)

Each of my points is like a wireless access point and cannot be on the same radio channel as another wireless access point within 2km.

I have 8 radio channels I can use, they are Channel 0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63

Is there a way I can use QGIS to automatically generate a channel plan for me by QGIS working out channel numbers that are not going to be within 2km of each other.

[image: wireless Access Point Pic]

Comment: this sounds like a graph colouring problem to me

Comment: Thats what i suspected, time to get the pens and highlighters out!

Comment: To help others put forward a solution, do you need to distribute all 8 radio channels across your point data, or if a solution could be found with say 5 will that be acceptable?