# OD Matrix algorithm in QNEAT3 plugin (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix

I have two questions regarding OD Matrix algorithms in QNEAT3 plugin.

1. If I set the cost strategy as the fastest path, would the output be the travel time? If yes, is the output in seconds?
2. The output of OD Matrix with the shortest path cost strategy is in meters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QNEAT3 output when selecting fastest path is in seconds, representing the travel time.

Shortest path: the output is in layer units, so it depends on the CRS of your layer. Be sure to have your layer in a CRS where distance measurements makes sense (projected CRS, one that is valid for your region of research). To find a suitable CRS, see here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382608/88814

To find out the CRS of your layer: Right click layer, Properties, Information tab, see screenshot (*be aware: `EPSG:3857` is not apt to measure distances!)*:

[image]